# LASSO confidence interval in a randomized experiment

Tags: confidence-interval, lasso, regularization

I want to use the LASSO for analyzing the results of a randomized experiment. I have more covariates than data, hence the motivation for using the LASSO. The treatment that was randomized in the experiment appears to be insignificant and the resulting LASSO model sets the beta coefficient for the treatment indicator to 0.

What I really want is a confidence interval for this treatment effect. Is there a way to get a CI for a LASSO parameter, particularly one that has been set to 0?

My alternative is to just use the LASSO to select covariates and then do an ordinary regression using these parameters, but this seems unprincipled somehow.

Any advice on what to do in a situation like this?

Comment: The general approach to this kind of thing is the bootstrap.  Using it, I often report 1) the proportion of times the estimated coefficient was zero, and 2) the conditional variance of a coefficient, given that it is non-zero.

Comment: If you had a prior hypothesis with regard to the treatment that you randomized, it might make sense to omit that treatment variable from penalization and restrict the LASSO to the other variables, which you consider to be covariates. Ridge regression might also make sense.